# How to get page 1 of total pages

Tags: context

Is it possible to have page numbering which looks like:

`Page 1 of n`

where `n` is the total number of pages in the document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of pages is stored in `\totalnumberofpages`, so it looks like you can do for example `\setupheadertexts[Page \pagenumber{} of \totalnumberofpages]`.

```
\usemodule[ipsum] % for dummy text

\setupheadertexts[Page \pagenumber{} of \totalnumberofpages]
\starttext
\ipsum\ipsum\ipsum\ipsum\ipsum\ipsum\ipsum\ipsum\ipsum\ipsum\ipsum\ipsum\ipsum
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to learn Context but didn't see that in any of the documentation. Do you know where I could have found it.

Comment: @pdoak I just googled, but in general look at http://wiki.contextgarden.net. See the links in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

`Page \pagenumber{} of \totalnumberofpages`

Or

`Page \pagenumber{} of \lastpage`

The first gives the total number of pages while the second gives the last userpage.

See http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/totalnumberofpages and
http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/lastpagenumber